# Get all static properties from a class

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I know that there are many questions like this, but I couldn't find any answer to what I'm trying to do.

Considering the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class TestBase
{
    public static ITest Test => Container.Resolve<ITest>();
    public static ITest1 Test1 => Container.Resolve<ITest1>();
    public static ITest2 Test2 => Container.Resolve<ITest2>();
    public static ITest3 Test3 => Container.Resolve<ITest3>();
}
```

I'm trying to get all the properties that inherit from an interface IDummy like this:

```
    var members = typeof(TestBase).GetMembers(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
        .Where(f => f.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IDummy)) == true);
```

but the list is empty. Without adding the where clause "`.Where(f => f.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IDummy)) == true)`" I get all the results including the getters for the properties.

Probably is something trivial, but as I'm not so familiar with reflection I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Since your first reference to `IDummy` is in how you're trying to *find* instances of this interface, does it not suggest that your code example preceding it is rather... incomplete?

Comment: Shouldn't that `IsAssignableFrom` be the other way around?

Comment: Fields do not have getters, and what you are declaring appear to be properties, not fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you get back from `GetMembers` is `MemberInfo` instances (or, for fields, `FieldInfo` instances). Hence, you cannot check these objects directly for being assignable from `IDummy`.

What you actually want to do is filter the `MemberInfo` objects for fields, then check the `FieldType` property of each of these objects:

```
var members = typeof(TestBase).GetMembers(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    .OfType<FieldInfo>()
    .Where(f => typeof(IDummy).IsAssignableFrom(f.FieldType));
```

Also, note that I turned around the subject and object of the `IsAssignableFrom` call, as also suggested in [Patrick's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55295839/get-all-static-fields-from-a-class/55295903#comment97319981_55295839).

---

As I just noticed, your example seems to show *properties* rather than *fields*. The general technique is the same, though; just use `PropertyInfo` and `PropertyType` rather than `FieldInfo` and `FieldType`, respectively.

Lastly, rather than filtering for `PropertyInfo` yourself, you could also use the one of the overloads of the `GetProperties` method directly.